# remove and reinstall rubygems (reinstall RVM)

Tags: ruby, rubygems, rvm, bundler

I ran into a problem with some gems, so I was told I should remove them with `rm -rf ~/.rvm`.

What do I have to do now in order to reinstall the gems? I instinctively ran `bundle install` in the directory where my `Gemfile` is, but, of course, it gives me now this error:

`bash: /home/bitnami/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2@global/bin/bundle: No such file or directory`

I guess the `rm -rf ~/.rvm` was not the right choice here. May someone help me with this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Install rvm again:

[Install rvm](https://rvm.io/rvm/install)

To uninstall gem simply,

```
 gem uninstall <gem-name>
```

To uninstall a particular version of gem:

```
gem uninstall <gem-name> --version <gem-version>
```

Answer (score 1):

To remove a gemset

```
rvm gemset delete <gemset-name>
```

since you have removed `~/.rvm`, you need reinstall rvm